# How to pass a value back from a function?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ by myself through online open class now. Here is a simple piece of code that I don't quite understand. I understand why it prints `a=3` at last: the code only passes the value of `a` to the `change` function, so `change` function cannot make changes to `a`, but where does the `30` in the change function go, and how can i print it? Thank  you!!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int change(int c)
{
    c=30;
    return c;
}
int main()
{
    int a=3;
    change(a);

    cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not assigning the return value of `change()` to the variable `a`. To change the value of `a` you should do `a = change(a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `c` is stored in temporary memory which is allocated when the function is called and can only be accessed by that specific function call.

EDIT: Apparently the real question is how you use the return value.

In essence, the return value of a function 'replaces' that function once it is finished executing. In this case, `change(a)` is replaced by 30, but you should know you can't just type integers in the code. You have to assign them. Because of this, you should instead write `a = change(a)` which ends up looking like `a = 30`. (or declare another integer ie. `int b = change(a)`).

This makes the new value of `a` become the return value of `change()`. (It doesn't form some crazy infinite loop because `change(a)` is executed before the assignment is done)

Comment: Or use the `return` value (which is a better idea IMHO)

Comment: @PawełStawarz Ah I didn't realise what he was meant to be asking. Updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't assign the return value to the variable.

You should use

```
a = change(a);
```

or

```
void change(int &c) // pass c by reference to make it changeable by such function
{
    c=30;
}
```